# how to interpret the smp_affinity output

Tags: linux, interrupt, affinity, irq

My lscpu output is:

[image]

I have only one entry in /proc/interrupts for my NIC:

[image]

smp_affinity for my NIC eth0 is:

[image]

Since I have only 8 CPUs, I expected the smp_affinity value to have 8 bits, each bit for one CPU core, but I have 32 bits.

How do I interpret this output? Is there a standard on how smp_affinity value is stored?

Answer (score 0):

smp_affinity format you find here:
[kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/IRQ-affinity.txt)

Comment: I saw this. It shows 8 bits for 8 cpu. My question is regarding that. I have 32 bits for a 8 CPU core

Comment: There is only one bit for the each CPU.
In your example 00000000,00000080 you assign to CPU with index 7.
you have 4 dwords becuase probably MAX_CPU in Linux configuration is 128.